# Overloading << Operator to Print Vector Data Member

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector, operator-overloading

I created a class with a private vector that uses std::string as its data type.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Pokemon {
public:
//Constructor - leaving it here for reference
Pokemon(std::string name, int LVL, int HP, int ATK, int DEF, int SPATK, int SPDEF, int SPD, 
std::vector<std::string>moves, std::vector<int>PP);
//Member Functions
std::vector<std::string> getMoves();
private:
std::vector<std::string>moves;
};
```

In order to retrieve information from this vector, I created a public class function titled getMoves(), which is supposed to return all of the information from that vector. Here's the function definition that I wrote in the .cpp file.

```
std::vector<std::string> Pokemon::getMoves() {
    return moves;
}
```

After attempting to print the vector which has these moves with std::cout and receiving a "no match for operator" error, I realized that I had to overload the << operator.

I have several questions on how to go about overloading the << operator so my vector will print.

1. I'm uncertain where to declare the overload operator.Do I declare it before my class? Inside my class as a public friend function? In a different header file? Inside my main function?
2. What type am I supposed to be overloading to print? I believe it'd be the same type as my class because the getMoves() function belongs to the Pokemon class but I'm unsure if it's that or `std::vector<std::string>`

   3. How do I utilize this overloaded operator within my main function? Just like a normal std::cout?

I'd appreciate any help with these questions, thank you!

Comment: You can put `vector<std::string>` in back ticks to escape the `<>`

Comment: @BennoStraub noted, thank you!

Comment: You can make wrapper class for `vector` and overload operator <<.

Comment: your question is too broad. Please one question per question. Anyhow, this should help to clarify some of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: @user463035818 I appreciate the link on the topic, thank you! Sorry for asking a couple questions in one question, I'll remember that in the future

Comment: @NutCracker gotcha, thanks! So I'd be wrapping both the vector and overload operator under a single class? I'm uninformed on wrappers but I'll definitely look into them now!

Comment: a wrapper can be as simple as `struct my_vector { std::vector<std::string> data; };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following example will overload `<<` operator for each vector. If you want to specify the output for your specific vector then make a wrapper struct or class.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

template <typename T> 
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<T>& v) 
{ 
    os << "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { 
        os << v[i]; 
        if (i != v.size() - 1) 
            os << ", "; 
    }
    os << "]\n";
    return os; 
}
```

Now when you want to print the vector like this:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> a = {0, 1, 2};
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

it will print the following result: `[0, 1, 2]`

Comment: Really appreciate the help! I didn't think about how useful templates would be with this. This is more efficient than overloading a single type right?

Comment: I would recommend you to create your own wrapper class and make a dedicated overload of `<<` operator. This is always a better way I would say than overloading the whole standard `vector` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

// Helper Function to Print Test Containers (Vector and Map)
template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair<T, U>& p) {
    out << "[" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "]";
    return out;
} 

template <template <typename, typename...> class ContainerType, typename 
ValueType, typename... Args>
void print_container(const ContainerType<ValueType, Args...>& c) {
    for (const auto& v : c) {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

As NutCracker mentioned `operator <<` overload is your best friend in almost all type of containers. In addition to his nice answer, here is a little bit extended version of templated resolution to print all type of STL containers.

Basically overloading for pair type of containers in addition to vectors. As an example. `ValueType -> First or only Element in container template` and `Args... variadic template as rest of the elements in container` (second or more elements)
For `pair <T,U>` basic map-unordered_map you only have first and second elements to `overload`
You can apply this technique to almost all container types.
If you just want to print each Pokemon features without calling any additional function `pokemon::getMoves()` you can `overload << for pokemon class` as well it might be better to print only 1 pokemon etc.

`friend` to give access to private and public members

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Pokemon& pokemonobj) {
    os << print_container(pokemonobj.getMoves());
    return os;
}
```